# Center text directly beneath a right-aligned heading

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

With LaTeX, how do I center text directly beneath a right-aligned heading? Maybe it's better explained with my attempt so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ hmargin = 1in, vmargin = 1in ]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}\huge Some Heading\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
    \raggedleft {\huge Another Heading} \\
    \centering  \today
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `minipage` requires a width argument, so the only way I can get the second line perfectly centered is if I guess (ahead of time) the exact width that the heading will be after it's rendered. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ hmargin = 1in, vmargin = 1in ]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\linewidth}\huge Some Heading\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\huge Another Heading \\
\today
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 it never occurred to me that `tabular` doesn't require a width... nice and simple

Comment: @MichaelKropat tabular is used in this way in many of the standard class frontmatter elements eg article sets each `\author` as a tabular for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

David's `tabular` solution works great, but I often resort to using `\makebox` to create a box of the desired width and align the text within that "box".  Below I show how to `c`enter, `r`ight, and `l`eft align the text within a box which is as wide as the`\widthof{\huge Another Heading}`:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `\widthof` macro is from [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ hmargin = 1in, vmargin = 1in ]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}\huge Some Heading\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \raggedleft {\huge Another Heading} \\
    \makebox[\widthof{\huge Another Heading}][c]{\today} \\
    \makebox[\widthof{\huge Another Heading}][r]{\today} \\
    \makebox[\widthof{\huge Another Heading}][l]{\today}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 wow, with the `\widthof` macro, you could roll your own solution to any number of alignment challenges

Answer (score 1):

Stack it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ hmargin = 1in, vmargin = 1in ]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
{\huge Some Heading}
\hfill
\stackunder[2pt]{\huge Another Heading}{\today}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelKropat Thanks for taking the time to look.  If you need those same features with tabbing, the `tabstackengine` package provides a wrapper around `stackengine`, which provides tabbing `&` columns.